# xCode TFS git Reposity - not able to pull changes when uncommited changes

Tags: ios, xcode, git, tfs

I have created remote repository on TFS server and successfully able to push and pull changes to/from server but able to checkout only by one user at a time.

So, while more than one user, when i need to take updates(pull changes), i have to discard my current changes. (Getting error - The working copy "" has uncommitted changes)

Also, i have tried solution :
 - .gitignore 
 - rm cached

Can anybody please assist!

Thanks

Comment: You need to deal with your uncommitted changes before you can pull from the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a PULL when you have uncommitted local changes. You need to deal with them first.

1. Commit them - If you commit the changes locally you can PULL and merge the incoming changes with the local ones.
2. Branch and Commit - If you create a branch and checkout it immediately your uncommitted changes will be poured across and you can commit there.
3. Undo - You can undo the local changes and then PULL, however you just lost hose changes.
4. Copy - You can manually copy the changes out of the Git repo, and then back in after.

I would recommend either #1 or #2 as the only realistic options.

Comment: Thanks MrHinsh, is there a way i can handle only on master branch?

Comment: I would recommend that you never commit and push directly to MASTER and instead create a DEVELOP line for your daily work. Then merge to MASTER when you have good code.

Comment: However in direct answer, no. You can't have any locally uncommitted changes when you do a PULL. Git is protecting those local changes from being overwritten.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you feedback on creating branch rather then working on master!

Is it possible to merge my local changes while pulling changes from server (in merge tool)?
Because it will be very difficult in multiple user scenario to revert my all changes to pull changes from server..

Comment: You only need to remove "uncommitted" changes. If you pull from the server and you have committed local changes you will get a merge.